# "Stored User Names and Passwords"-Applet not working in Windows 11 (rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr)

Tags: windows-11, credentials, credentials-manager, applet

Windows 10 used to support the classic "Stored User Names and Passwords"-Applet via the command `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr`. Windows 11, according to statements from other users' comments, should still support this.

When I execute the command (Windows 11 Pro V10.0.22000), the applet doesn't open (there is no error message), I tried the regular as well as the elevated shell (I tried CMD as well):

```
PS C:\Users\username> rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr
PS C:\Users\username>
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: The command you show works in Window 11 Pro just the same as Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, good to know! Then the question is, why doesn't work for me?

Comment: It works in Windows 11 Production and more Advanced Windows 11 Insider.  I am not sure why not for you. Try running DISM and SFC to see if that corrects the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, no results using DISM and SFC. I'm using Windows 11 Pro V10.0.22000

Comment: Try using Cmd instead of Power Shell and see if that works

Comment: Already tried that, and normal as well as elevated mode unfortunately it gives me the same results

Comment: See if you can find another Windows 11 machine nearby you to test. Certainly working here.

Comment: I just realized the command string works in Power Shell as well as CMD.  Consider a Windows 11 Repair install.

Comment: why the repair-install if dism and fsc don't indicate any problems (except for trying a shot in the dark, which of course might work)?

Comment: Try Credentials Manager, which usually does not show corrupt credentials. Do you see any credentials? In case of credential corruption, you could also see [How to clear all Credentials from Credential Manager](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/clear-all-credentials-from-credential-manager) (if losing all your stored credentials is not a problem).

Comment: A repair install is much more detailed and expansive than DISM which why I suggest it to fix your system.

Comment: I answered your question on NIC Public / Private appearance and I think the issues you put forward to my answer relates to your computer not working correctly.

Comment: Thx a lot for your help, repair-install wasn't necessary. In this case the difficulty was that the "Stored User Names and Passwords"-Applet does not show up as an entry in the taskbar but it does show up as an entry in the device manager: `rundll32`. If, for some reason, it started behind other windows (this was the case for me), executing the command again doesn't affect anything, since it's already running. Using Process Explorer, for example, it's possible to bring the window to the front. Thx again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Stored User Names and Passwords"-Applet does not show up as an entry in the taskbar but it does show up as an entry the device manager `rundll32`.

If, for some reason, it started behind other windows (this was the case for me), executing the command again doesn't affect anything, since it's already running. Using Process Explorer, for example, it's possible to bring the window to the front.